# excluding specific strings (DNA string) from background (DNA sequence) and shuffling (i.e. generating negative set from positive DNA sequence)

Tags: r, string, replace, dna-sequence

I have fasta file including strings of DNA. I want to generate a negative dataset from positive data. One way is to exclude some specific sequences from my data and then shuffle the data.
Let's say my dataset is a list:

```
1)
DNAlst:
ACTATACGCTAATATCGATCTACGTACGATCG
CAGCAGCAGCGAGACTATCCTACCGCA
ATATCGATCGCAAAAATCG
```

I want to exclude these sequences:

```
ATAT,CGCA
```

so the result would be:

```
ACTATACGCTACGATCTACGTACGATCG
CAGCAGCAGCGAGACTATCCTAC
CGATAAAAATCG
```

`2)` then I want to shuffle my sequence by a specific length (e.g. 5). It means to shuffle DNA string by part (5-mer) with length of 5. For example:

`ATATACGCGAAAAAATCTCTC => result after shuffle by 5 ==> AAAAACTCTCCGCAATATA`

I would be thankful you if tell me how to do this in R.

Comment: A simple `gsub` can do the first part, something like `gsub("ATAT|CGCA", "", "CAGCAGCAGCGAGACTATCCTACCGCA")` though I'm not sure what is you data structure a `dput(DNAlst)` could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stringi` package:

```
dna <- c("ACTATACGCTAATATCGATCTACGTACGATCG","CAGCAGCAGCGAGACTATCCTACCGCA","ATATCGATCGCAAAAATCG")

# stri_replace function replaces strings ATAT and CGCA for empty string
stri_replace_all_regex(dna, "ATAT|CGCA","")
```

Now the shuffle part. `seq` and `stri_sub` functions will be useful. First we need to 'cut' our DNA seq into pieces of at most 5 char long. seq function give us starting points

```
seq(1,24,5)
## [1]  1  6 11 16 21
seq(1,27,5)
## [1]  1  6 11 16 21 26
```

`stri_sub` string from indexes generated by `seq` of length 5

```
y <- stri_sub(dna[1], seq(from=1,to=stri_length(dna[1]),by=5), length = 5)
y
## [1] "ACTAT" "ACGCT" "AATAT" "CGATC" "TACGT" "ACGAT" "CG"
```

`sample` will shuffle our vector and `stri_flatten` paste it together into one string.

```
stri_flatten(y[sample(length(y))])
## [1] "TACGTACGATCGATCAATATACGCTACTATCG"
```